# .NET 6 Class Library with Winforms (output as DLL)

Tags: winforms, .net-6.0, excel-dna

I'm trying to migrate a Class library project from .NET Framework using Excel DNA to .NET 6 - The project needs to output as a Class Library however also needs to include winforms - is there a way to achieve this in .NET 6?

(This was working without issue in .NET Framework)

Comment: If your Project file specifies `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>`, `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` and `<OutputType>` is absent, you have a class Library with WinForms dependencies. -- You haven't described what kind of problem you have.

Comment: Thanks Jimi That did the trick! 

The issue I was having was I needed VS to create a DLL - however when I enabled windows forms it would only output a EXE. (When using VS2022, .NET6 & Excel DNA.) - Manually editing the project file to remove <OutputType> fixed my issues.